# zookeeper cluster configuration on two servers

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I want to build a cluster using zookeeper, but I just get 2 servers(A,B). If I install two zookeepers(`z1`, `z2`) on server A, and one(`z3`) on server B. Can this cluster work?
In fact, I have configured my servers like this. `z2` can start, but I can not check its status. And `z1` and `z3` are standalone mode. How to configure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this cluster work?

Yes, you can install three instances on two servers. You just need different configurations for z1 and z2.

Use the following configuration for z1.

```
# z1 configuration
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
dataDir=/data/z1
clientPort=2181
server.1=A:2888:3888
server.2=A:2889:3889
server.3=B:2888:3888
```

and this one for z2.

```
# z2 configuration
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
dataDir=/data/z2
clientPort=2182
server.1=A:2888:3888
server.2=A:2889:3889
server.3=B:2888:3888
```

on z3 configuration you need to have these lines. So z3 will be aware of z1 and z2. If you don't add these, z1 and z2 will be running standalone.

```
server.1=A:2888:3888
server.2=A:2889:3889
server.3=B:2888:3888
```

To check the status of a node, simply look inside zookeper.out file under dataDir. It will print enough information about the status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question. On apache.zookeeper.org, they require "all servers in the quorum have copies of the same configuration file" . What does this sentence means? If I install two zookeepers on a server, their configurations cannot be the same?

Comment: You are right. You need to have different dataDir and clientPort values for each instance on the same host. That sentence on zookeeper documentation tries to remind you that some entries in configuration file define how a zookeeper instance works. Entries like tickTime, initLimit, syncLimit and server.X are important and zookeeper uses them for leader selection, failover, etc. When different values are used, each instance will act differently so your cluster may not work as expected.

Comment: Also remember that zookeeper documentation recommends installing only one zookeeper instance per host. If you install all your nodes on a different servers you can use exactly the same configuration. I guess "all servers in the quorum have copies of the same configuration file" sentence assumes your zookeeper instances are installed on different servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I install two zookeepers on server A, and a zookeeper on server B. After configuration, I found these two zookeepers on server A are a cluster, but cannot work. While the zookeeper on server B is standalone. I guess if I want to build a cluster with three zookeepers, they should be installed on three servers, instead of two servers.

Comment: Server count is not a limitation to build a zk cluster. I do some of my tests with 5 zk instances on one server. Can you post your zk configurations, so I can see if there is an configuration error?

Comment: 1. initLimit=5 synLimit=2 clientPort=2183
dataDir=/home/cvs/data/zk1
Server.1=192.168.233.98:2888:3888
Server.2=192.168.233.99:2888:3888
Server.3=192.168.233.99:2889:3889   2.initLimit=5
synLimit=2 clientPort=2183 dataDir=/home/cvs/data/zk2
Server.1=192.168.233.98:2888:3888
Server.2=192.168.233.99:2888:3888
Server.3=192.168.233.99:2889:3889  3.nitLimit=5
synLimit=2 clientPort=2182
dataDir=/home/cvs/data/zk3
Server.1=192.168.233.98:2888:3888
Server.2=192.168.233.99:2888:3888
Server.3=192.168.233.99:2889:3889.  But I install all zks on two servers, not one servers. THX.

Comment: thanks, i see two typos in your configuration. The first one is synLimit, it should be syncLimit; and the second one is nitLimit in 3rd file. Do they exist in actual configuration files or is it just a copy & paste error?